# How to reverse_lazy to a view/url with variable?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I've got a `DeleteView` I use for removing objects from a model. It is launched via a button in a table. It works fine.

```
class DeleteAssignment(DeleteView):
  model = Assignment
  success_url = reverse_lazy('company')
```

[image: Screenshot]

I just want to have it return to it's parent view on success. I currently have it redirecting to the parent's parent (`company`), as this view doesn't require a variable. This would be simple, but the parent view requires a variable `farm_id` to render, this is captured from the url like "/farm/18"

```
url(r'^farm/(?P<farm_id>.+)', views.farm, name='farm'),
```

I've solved this with forms on the page by having them redirect to the view `farm` with the variable `farm_id`.

```
return redirect(farm, farm_id=farm_id)
```

How could I do this with the `success_url` for my `DeleteView`?

Example for nickie:

**views.py**

```
 @login_required
    def farm(request, farm_id=None):
        user = request.user
        company_id = user.profile.company_id
        farm_id = farm_id
        farm_filter = Farm.objects.filter(farm=farm_id)
        farm_current = farm_filter[0]
        # farm_company =
        serial_filter = Sensor.objects.filter(assignment__farm__company_id__isnull=True)
        assignment_filter = Assignment.objects.filter(farm=farm_id)
        farm_instance = Farm.objects.get(farm=farm_filter[0].farm)
        update_farm_form = UpdateFarmForm(instance=farm_instance)
        assign_sensor_form = AssignmentForm()

        if request.method == 'POST' and 'updatefarm' in request.POST:
            update_farm_form = UpdateFarmForm(request.POST, instance=farm_instance)
            if update_farm_form.is_valid():
                update_farm_form.save()
                return redirect(farm, farm_id=farm_id)
        else:
            if request.method == "POST" and 'assignsensor' in request.POST:
                assign_sensor_form = AssignmentForm(request.POST)
                if assign_sensor_form.is_valid():
                    assignment = assign_sensor_form.save()
                    if user.is_staff is True:
                        assignment.company_id = farm_filter[0].company_id
                    else:
                        assignment.company_id = user.profile.company_id
                    assignment.save()
                    return redirect(farm, farm_id=farm_id)
                else:
                    assign_sensor_form = AssignmentForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'users/farm_template.html', {'company_id': company_id, 'farm_filter': farm_filter, 'farm_current': farm_current, 'serial_filter': serial_filter, 'assignment_filter': assignment_filter, 'update_farm_form': update_farm_form, 'assign_sensor_form': assign_sensor_form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from apps.dashboard import views
from apps.dashboard.views import DeleteAssignment, DeleteFarm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^company/', views.company_view, name='company'),
    # url(r'^test/', views.test),
    # url(r'^test2/', views.test2, name='test2'),
    # url(r'^farms/', views.add_farms),
    url(r'^manual-signup/', views.signup_manual),
    url(r'^signup/(?P<company_id>.+)', views.signup_company),
    url(r'^settings/', views.update_profile),
    url(r'^create-company/', views.create_company),
    url(r'^create-sensor/', views.create_sensor),
    url(r'^assign-sensor/', views.assign_sensor),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^$', views.main),
    # url(r'^company/(?P<company_id>.+)/farm/(?P<farm_id>.+)', views.farm),
    url(r'^farm/(?P<farm_id>.+)', views.farm, name='farm'),
    url(r'^unit/(?P<sensor_id>.+)', views.unit),
    # url(r'^company/(?P<company_id>.+)', views.company),
    url(r'^download/', views.download),
    # url(r'^export/xls/$', views.export_users_xls),
    url(r'^live/', views.live),
    url(r'^data/', views.data),
    url(r'^debug/', views.debug),
    url(r'^delete-assignment/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DeleteAssignment.as_view(), name='delete-assignment', ),
    url(r'^delete-farm/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DeleteFarm.as_view(), name='delete-farm', ),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

This is view redirects to itself upon successful form submission. This reloads tables based on the user submission without having to deal with js for now.

The `farm_id` in `return redirect(farm, farm_id=farm_id)` is captured from the url, via the appropriate line in **urls.py** `url(r'^farm/(?P<farm_id>.+)', views.farm, name='farm'),`

This is all I want to do with the delete view, instead of the success url simply being a view, a view with a variable like I did above.

Comment: I suppose you have seen [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeletionMixin.success_url) and it's not enough for you.

Comment: You need to add **urls.py** so that people understand what you exactly want to do.

Comment: @nickie That worked perfectly! Don't know how I missed it. `success_url = "/farm/{farm_id}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nickie suggested in the comments: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeletionMixin.success_url

Solved this with `success_url = "/farm/{farm_id}"`

Comment: This works, but using named urls is a better practice overall. The other answer is superior IMO.

Comment: For someone stuck for hours on a simple url redirect to a url containing a primary key this post was a life saver

Answer (score 28):

**Yes**, you can do this with `success_url` in this way:

```
class DeleteAssignment(DeleteView):
    . . . . . 
    . . . . . 

    . . . . . 
    def get_success_url(self):
          # if you are passing 'pk' from 'urls' to 'DeleteView' for company
          # capture that 'pk' as companyid and pass it to 'reverse_lazy()' function
          companyid=self.kwargs['pk']
          return reverse_lazy('company', kwargs={'pk': companyid})
```

This should work perfectly.

Comment: Since I am adding that below, what should I change the `success_url = reverse_lazy('company')` line to?

Comment: replace in above code `return reverse_lazy('company', kwargs={'farm_id': farmid})`

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
reverse_lazy('name_of_your_view', kwargs={'key': value})
```

Not documented either in the man page or in docstring, was suggested by AI.